# Why doesn't this code compile

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    const int NUMROWS=3; 
    const int NUMCOLS=4;
    int i,j; 
    int val[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS]={8,16,9,52,27,6,14,25,2,10};//multiply each element by 10 and display it 
    cout<<"\nDisplay or multiplied elements"; 
    for(i=0; i<NUMROWS;i++)
    {
        val[i][j]=val[i][j]*10;
    }//end of inner loop
    }//end of outer loop
    cout<endl; 
    return 0; 
    }
```

These are the errors I received. What have I done wrong 16:5: error: 'cout' does not name a type
17:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
18:5: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: `cout<endl` should be `cout<<endl`

Comment: Indent you code. There's end of 2 loops, but only one loop in the code.

Comment: You also seem to have an extraneous closing brace before `cout<endl;` which as tobi303 has correctly identfied should be double arrow `<<`

Comment: the value of `j` is undefined

Comment: This might also interest you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your inner for loop and your cout after the double for loop is missing a second carrot. Should probably look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    const int NUMROWS=3; 
    const int NUMCOLS=4;
    int i,j; 
    int val[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS]={8,16,9,52,27,6,14,25,2,10};//multiply each element by 10 and display it 
    cout<<"\nDisplay or multiplied elements"; 
    for(i=0; i<NUMROWS;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<NUMCOLS;j++)
        {
            val[i][j]=val[i][j]*10;
        }//end of inner loop
    }//end of outer loop
    cout<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

```
}//end of outer loop
cout<endl;
```

First, while your comment says "end of outer loop", the brace actually closes `main`, so the code is incorrect. That is why you're getting the error on `cout` doesn't name a type.

Once you delete that brace, you'll get a huge compile error starting with:

> error: no match for ‘`operator<`’ in ‘`std::cout < std::endl`’

because you wrote `cout < endl;` when you meant `cout << endl`;

Answer (score 1):

Typos:

```
  cout<endl;
```

You have a missing `<`
 It should have been:

```
 cout<<endl;
```

Place the above inside `main`, currently it is outside the scope of `main`.

Other issues:

```
 val[i][j]=val[i][j]*10;
```

`j` here is uninitialized.

```
  }//end of outer loop
```

You haven't defined any outer `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a `for` loop for the `j` index:

```
for(i=0; i<NUMROWS;i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<NUMCOLS;j++)
    {
        val[i][j]=val[i][j]*10;
    }//end of inner loop
}//end of outer loop
```

Also note that you missed a `<` character `cout<endl;` should be `cout<<endl;`

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile because it is not a valid C++ program.

One problem is that you have more closing brackets than opening ones. I would suggest to use a source code editor that indicates what bracktes belong to each other.